# PorterDuffColorFilter changes all icons in my recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, porter-duff, colorfilter

so - I have a recyclerview and if I click on an item I want to change the colorFilter of my drawable that is attached to my textView in the position clicked.

the problem is, when I change the color of my drawable, it changes in all items instead of only the position clicked.

code:

```
for (drawable: Drawable? in textView.compoundDrawablesRelative) {
    drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(textView.context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
}
```

this for-loop is being called in the 'onBindViewHolder' of my adapter, when I'm clicking - I'm calling notifyItemChanged with my position, I've triple checked it, this function only runs a single time with my correct position clicked.. so why does everything changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of `Drawable`:

> By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.

You need to get a new instance (actually only the state is new most of the times) of that drawable which doesn't share the state anymore using the [`mutate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) method.

Comment: Exactly the explanation I was missing, forgot about that! thank you :)